# Creating NULL values in db for OneToMany relationship between User and Message

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to create a OneToMany relationship between a User class and a Message class. A user can have multiple messages. But when I persist it in db, I get Null values in the tables;

Here is my code
**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;


    @OneToMany
    private List<Message> messages;

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public User() {

    }
    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.username = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

**Message.java**

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String content;


    @Type(type="timestamp")
    private Date created;

    public Message() {

    }


    public Message(String user, String receiver, String content) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.content = content;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(User sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

**MessageDAOImpl.java**

```
public class MessageDAOImpl implements MessageDAO {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageDAO.class);
    private static Session session;

    private static void beginSession() {
        session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
        beginSession();
        sendMessage(message, session);
        session.close();
    }

    public void sendMessage(Message message, Session session) {
      User user = new User();
      List<Message> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(message);
        user.setMessages(list);

        try {
            session.save(user);
            session.save(message);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            LOG.error("Cannot save the message", e);
        }
    }
```

MainClass
**Solution.java**

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Message message = new Message("HELP", "HELPER", "PLEASE HELP");
        MessageDAOImpl mess = new MessageDAOImpl();
        mess.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

This is creating null entries in the database.

```
mysql> select * from user;
   +----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
        | id | password                                                     | username    |
        +----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+
        |  1 | $2a$10$.wjZcxcnyZV45cUhofl7gG64GYoekSOa | testUser123 |
        |  2 | NULL                                                         | NULL        |
        |  3 | NULL                                                         | NULL        |
        +----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+

mysql> select * from Message;
+----+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | content                     | created             | receiver            | sender_id |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | This is good | 2017-05-03 11:17:27 | testReceivedFromCfg |      NULL |
|  2 | This challenge is good | 2017-05-03 11:28:25 | testReceivedFromCfg |      NULL |
|  3 | PLEASE HELP                 | 2017-05-03 11:35:22 | HELPER              |      NULL |
+----+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+

mysql> select * from user_message;
+---------+-------------+
| User_id | messages_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       2 |           2 |
|       3 |           3 |
+---------+-------------+
```

My question is that, a user can send multiple messages. If you directly call `sendMessage`, `message` should be sent only if `sender` and `receier` are present in `User table`. But right now its populating the db with NULL value.  How can I modify my code?

The process is 
`1) The user registers with username and password`. 
`2) Sends message to receiver who is also in the db.`
Message can be sent only if sender and receiver are in db.

Comment: Read the documentation on how to create a bidirectional one-to-many association. That's not what you have here. What you have is two unidirectional associations, each mapped differently (one using a join table user_message, one using a join column sender_id). https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional. It's really as simple as reading the documentation.

Comment: But, when I pass `String sender` in my `Message constructor`, its treating User as NULL. How can I fix it?

Comment: There is no sender argument at all in your Message constructor. You need to create the User, then pass the created user to the constructor of Message.

Comment: How can I pass a message without creating the User?. The process is 1) The user registers with username and password. 2) Sends message to receiver who is also in the db.

Comment: So you want to create a Message for a User that already exists in the DB? Get it from the DB (using em.find(), or em.getReference(), or a query), then pass it to your Message constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be a bit mixed up. First of all you need to connect the relations.

**Message class**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private User sender;
```

In my example I connect both Entities via the id of the User class. You can still use a different column in your db.

**User class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="sender")
@Fetch(value= FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Message> messages = null;
```

Add your needed cascadeTypes and change the FetchMode if you want. Add other parameters.

**DAO**

First of all, remove all code which does not belong to the DAO. Normally an update of a db-Entry can look as short as this:

```
@Transactional("hibernate")
@Override
public void updateMessage(Message transientObject) throws MyDaoException {
  Session session = getCurrentSession();
  session.save(message);
}
```

Same for the User.